# Upload file From AWS s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, angularjs-fileupload

I need help with getting file from AWS S3 bucket.What I want is when I click file browse to browse the file,till now I was uploading file through my local disk.But now what I want is when I click browse,it should show me to upload file from s3 bucket.I want this functionality to validate my files on s3 bucket according to some validations.Through local files,It's much easier but now need solution over uploading from AWS S3.How can I accomplish this?I am stuck.
Any help would be very much appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this from the console, and the other S3 bucket (that you want to upload from) is in your account, you can simply copy from that bucket and paste it in this bucket of yours.